# Download list of blobs from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

I have created `CloudBlobContainer` with the proper connection string:

```
@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public CloudBlobContainer blobContainer(CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount) {
    return cloudStorageAccount
            .createCloudBlobClient()
            .getContainerReference(containerName);
}
```

I see the list of blobs using `blobContainer.listBlobs()`

Currently, I am looking for the most efficient way to download list blobs from a particular folder.

Comment: Are you looking to download the blobs from a particular folder or just list the blobs from a folder?

Comment: @GauravMantri I need to download every blob from the folder that the container contains. Folder name will be the parameter of the request.

Answer (score 1):

`listBlobs()` method has an [`overload`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/legacy-master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlobContainer.java#L1256) which accepts `prefix` as a parameter.

```
public Iterable<ListBlobItem> listBlobs(final String prefix, final boolean useFlatBlobListing) {
        return this.listBlobs(prefix, useFlatBlobListing, EnumSet.noneOf(BlobListingDetails.class), null, null);
    }
```

You would need to pass the `path of the folder` as `prefix` and pass `true` for `useFlatBlobListing` and that will list all blobs in that virtual folder.

Once you have that list of blobs, you can then download the blobs using [`downloadToFile`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/legacy-master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.java#L1990) method on each blob.

Answer (score 1):

After some time I found that I can apply `CloudBlockBlob` type to `ListBlobItem` and download method.

```
@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(CloudBlobContainer blobContainer) {
    return args -> {
        Sets.newConcurrentHashSet(blobContainer.listBlobs("documents/"))
                .stream()
                .filter(it -> it.getUri().toString().contains("pdf"))
                .forEach(it -> {
                    ((CloudBlockBlob) it).downloadToFile(((CloudBlockBlob) it).getName());
                });

    };
}
```

Thanks, everyone. Especially @GauravMantri

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways via

(i) **`AZcopy`** - `AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/demo/ /Dest:C:\myfolder /SourceKey:key /S`

(ii) Via **`Azure Cli`** -

```
# Create a directory to store all the blobs
mkdir /downloaded-container && cd /downloaded-container

# Get all the blobs
BLOBS=$(az storage blob list -c $CONTAINER \
    --account-name $ACCOUNT_NAME --sas-token "$SAS_TOKEN" \
    --query [*].name --output tsv)

# Download each one
for BLOB in $BLOBS
do
  echo "********Downloading $BLOB"
  az storage blob download -n $BLOB -f $BLOB -c $CONTAINER --account-name $ACCOUNT_NAME --sas-token "$SAS_TOKEN"
done
```

if you want only through code, here is a **[`sample repo`](https://github.com/philippn/azure-sharedkey-auth/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/philippn/azureutils/AzureDownloader.java)** as there is no direct way to do via the SDK.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlString);
            signRequest(httpGet, resourcePath, account, hashFunction);
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
```